# Set intersection with custom comparator?

Tags: python

I have sets of strings

```
set_a = {'abcd', 'efgh', 'ghij'}
set_b = {'abce', 'efgk', 'ghij'}
```

I want to find the intersection between these two sets but element equality defined as the following

```
def match(string_a, string_b, threshold=0.8):
    lcs_len = lcs(string_a, item_set_b)
    return (lcs_len / max(len(string_a), len(item_set_b))) > 0.8
```

basically if the lcs is at least 80% of the length of the string we consider this matching "enough".  I know passing custom comparators to sorting methods works something like this but I haven't found anything for custom comparators in set operations.

Comment: You might want to choose longer strings for your example.  Even if 1 letter is not the same, only 75% of the letters will match, so the threshold only finds perfect matches here.

Comment: Nontransitive concepts of equality don't really work well, both on a theoretical level and in terms of the practical implementation of sets. So many things go wrong when `a == b and b == c` doesn't imply `a == c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the cartesian product of both sets, then keep the elements that are in both sets and satisfy your predicate

```
from itertools import product
{i for i,j in product(set_a, set_b) if i in set_b and match(i,j)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list compresion and adding a new function:

```
def match_with_set(string_a, set_b, threshold=0.8):
    for string in set_b:
        if match(string_a, string, threshold):
             return True
    return False

intersection_set = set([ string for string in set_a if match_with_set(string, set_b)])
```